# How to trace source of JQuery error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, debugging, opera

I have a page in my website that calls several javascript files/libraries that contain both standard javascript as well as JQuery, as well as JQuery code following them on the rest of the page. The console shows an error in the main JQuery initialization file (i.e., jquery.js, which enables JQuery for the other routines), but not the source of the error in the other routines. In other words, in one of the JQuery routines on the page--either in the libraries or the direct JQuery written on the page itself--something is triggering an error, and the best the console can do is report to me the line in jquery.js where the error is triggered, not the problem-causing JQuery code that makes use of jquery.js file.

I've used standard searching techniques for locating similar terms from that line in jquery.js in all of the files that are read by the page as well as on the page itself, but I can't identify it. I've also put console.log() statements throughout the jquery.js file to see if the error is reported before or after those console.log() statements, but that is no help.

I need to be able to trace the source of the error back from jquery.js to whichever jquery routine in whichever file is causing it.

The developer tools in each of the browsers only show the line in the jquery.js file where the error is thrown (it's a warning message about a deprecated feature, thus the page is rendered, but with the warning that I wish to attend to.) Curiously, it's only in Chrome and Opera that the developer's tools will show the error in the console. So, I cannot use Firefox or any of the other browsers for debugging this natively, as they do not reveal the warning message.

Is there (1) a plugin that will offer tracing like what I need, or (2) code I can put into jquery.js or within `<script>` tags before it is called to be able to trace the source of the offending command?

Comment: Tried using Inspect element to add break points and step through the code?

Comment: I don't know which element to inspect, as the page is displayed correctly. It's a general warning error about a deprecated feature in jquery.js that should be avoided.